# Difference between map[] and map.at in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

What is the difference in getting a value through `aMap[key]` and `aMap.at(key)` in C++?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In C++11 `map::at` exists (who knew?).

It throws an exception if the key doesn't exist, `find` returns `aMap.end()` if the element doesn't exist, and `operator[]` **value-initializes** a new value for the corresponding key if no value exists there.

Comment: @KerrekSB (since C++11) didn't know that though.

Answer (score 45):

If you access a key using the indexing operator `[]` that is not currently a part of a map, then it ***automatically adds a key for you***. This is a huge caveat, and take this into consideration. For this reason, I prefer using the indexing operator `[]` for setting, and `.find()` / `.at()` for lookup.

Another advantage of using `.at()` over `[]` is the fact that it can operate on a `const std::map`, whereas `[]` won't.