# Exception handling. How does one Throw an iterator?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, stdvector, stdmap

I'm not too familiar with exception handling so could someone help me with this problem?? So for this program, incase of a non-existing key in the std::map, I want to throw something but I dont know what.

the map key if it exists will be a phone number (string), but if it doesn't exist what would it be??

```
class SmartCarrier{
private:
    string carrier_name_;
    map<string,vector<Message*>> accounts_map;
public:
    Search();
}

void phone::Search{

    string phone_number;


    map<string,vector<Message*>>::iterator iter;


    cout << "Enter a phone number: ";
    getline(cin,phone_number);

try{
    iter = phone_map.find(phone_number);

    if (iter ==phone_map.end()) {
        //Incase of a non-existing phone number what do I throw? 
        throw iter;
    }

}
catch(/*iter ??? what should the block catch as a value?*/){
   cout << "Phone number not found." << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `iter`? That's what you need to catch. Not that it really matter in your case, since it will always be equal to `phone_map.end()`. I suggest you use [one of the standard exception classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error), perhaps making up your own based on a standard class.

Comment: Also for your information: While using exceptions have a negligible impact on performance if no exceptions are thrown, exceptions in C++ do have a sizeable impact on performance if you throw and catch one. Exceptions should only be used in *exceptional* cases. Failure to validate user input is usually not such an exceptional case.

Comment: I think this is a bad example of exception handling. You don't need try-catch block here at all.

Comment: What if I have fat fingers and type in a bad phone number?  You're going to throw an exception for that situation?  Humans typing in something wrong is *not* an exceptional case, as the previous comment pointed out.

Comment: Although this could be done in a much simpler way the specs for my assignment tell me to do so.  I guess my professor wants me to get used to exception handling. I honestly dont know when to use it and what "exceptional cases" refers to in this context.

Comment: An example of an exceptional case is one where the preconditions **must** be met, else there is something seriously wrong. A person typing something wrong is not one of those situations, it's simple user error and just ask to re-enter the information.   On the other hand, a data file generated from an outside source that should **never** be blank is discovered to be blank -- throw an exception.   Out of memory, or access the first item in an empty queue -- throw an exception.  Your professor is probably a Java programmer, where in Java throwing exceptions seems to be the norm for any error.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb - you always throw a derived class of `std::exception`, if not stated otherwise by some style guide. You can use already defined common exceptions, like `std::runtime_error`. And pass error data as exception argument, that's the whole point of exceptions - propagate the error data.

And always catch by const-reference.

In your case you might simply do:

```
try {
    auto iter = phone_map.find(phone_number);
    if (iter == phone_map.end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Incorrect phone number" };
    }
} catch(const std::exception& e){
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

In your case you can throw an iterator, and catch like this:

```
try {
    throw phone_map.end();
} catch (const map<string,vector<Message*>>::iterator& e) {
    // Do Something
}
```

But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that in this particular situation you don't need to throw any exceptions. The `Search` name of the function, from the reader standpoint, probably means that the only responsibility of the function is to check whether or not there's a such element in the map. Returning value by an exception is a very strange (and inefficient) way. Here I would use [`std::map::count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) - it returns `1` if such value is in the map, and `0` otherwise.

If you really need to throw an exception in case of abscence of value, look at [`std::map::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/). It throws an `std::out_of_range` exception if the key is not present.

For more info on `std::map::at()` and other methods of retrieval information from `std::map` please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33236261/1989995).