# C++ unordered_map weird behaviour

Tags: c++

I was solving leetcode problem (**Pairs of Songs With Total Durations Divisible by 60**) and my solution below uses a map, when I change it to an unordered_map and print the elements inside the loop; the number of elements are much more than the input

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numPairsDivisibleBy60(vector<int>& time) {
        map<int, int> mod_d;
        
        for(auto el : time) {
            if(mod_d.count(el % 60) == 0) {
                mod_d[el % 60] = 1;
            }else mod_d[el % 60]++;
        }
        
        int ans = 0, i = 1;
        //cout << "Size: " << mod_d.size() << "\n";
        for(auto el : mod_d) {
            int f = el.first, s = el.second;
            cout << f << " " << 60 - f << "\n";
            ans += mod_d[(60 - f) % 60] * (((60 - f) % 60) == f ? s - 1 : s);
        }
        
        return ans / 2;
    }
};
```

**Sample Input Test**: [15, 63, 451, 213, 37, 209, 343, 319]

And the output is as follows:

```
3 57
15 45
19 41
29 31
31 29
33 27
37 23
41 19
43 17
45 15
57 3
```

The number of elements printed should be only 8 inside the loop, but with an unordered_map, the elements are much more.

The code that is not working well is below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numPairsDivisibleBy60(vector<int>& time) {
        unordered_map<int, int> mod_d;
        
        for(auto el : time) {
            if(mod_d.count(el % 60) == 0) {
                mod_d[el % 60] = 1;
            }else mod_d[el % 60]++;
        }
        
        int ans = 0, i = 1;
        //cout << "Size: " << mod_d.size() << "\n";
        for(auto el : mod_d) {
            int f = el.first, s = el.second;
            cout << f << " " << 60 - f << "\n";
            ans += mod_d[(60 - f) % 60] * (((60 - f) % 60) == f ? s - 1 : s);
        }
        
        return ans / 2;
    }
};
```

### The only difference is the usage of `unordered_map` instead of a `map`

And it prints the elements wrongly as:

```
19 41
43 17
37 23
33 27
31 29
29 31
3 57
41 19
15 45
41 19
3 57
29 31
31 29
57 3
33 27
37 23
43 17
17 43
19 41
23 37
27 33
```

Anyone knows why is this odd behavior happening?

Comment: please show the code that has the problem instead of the one that does not have it ([mcve])

Comment: also include the output and the expected output

Comment: Alright will add them right now

Comment: The second for loop creates more elements in the map. maps and unordered maps, by definition, store their contents in different order, and it just so happens that with an unordered_map you end up iterating over the new elements in the map, as part of the same loop. With a regular map you don't.

Comment: Also please try to make your question self-contained, which means you need to tell us the exact problem you need to solve.

Comment: And you should take this as an opportunity to learn something competition sites doesn't teach (and honestly they barely teach anything except bad habits): **Debugging**. Using a *debugger* you can step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values to see what actually happens.

Comment: I have updated the question as per your suggestions, Thank you so much. I will try to use a debugger as well indeed.

Comment: in second loop try `map_d.at(...) ` instead of square brackets and see what happens

Comment: @j.holetzeck When I added a check if the `(60 - f) % 60)` is found and used `at()` the number of elements is indeed correct now :D. Can you please tell me why is that?

Comment: Alright I now understand, thank you so much all for the help. As per this link that shows the different ways to access a map, I see that using `[]` operator creates the elements if they are not there and that is my mistake.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236038/when-i-should-use-stdmapat-to-retrieve-map-element

Answer (score 1):

Alright I now understand, thank you so much all for the help. As per this link that shows the different ways to access a map, I see that using `[]` operator creates the elements if they are not there in the map and that is my mistake. [When I should use std::map::at to retrieve map element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236038/when-i-should-use-stdmapat-to-retrieve-map-element)

## Fix

**Checking if the element exist at first and using `at()` to access it**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numPairsDivisibleBy60(vector<int>& time) {
        unordered_map<int, int> mod_d;

        for(auto el : time) {
            if(mod_d.count(el % 60) == 0) {
                mod_d[el % 60] = 1;
            }else mod_d[el % 60]++;
        }

        int ans = 0, i = 1;
        cout << "Size: " << mod_d.size() << "\n";
        for(auto el : mod_d) {
            int f = el.first, s = el.second;
            cout << f << " " << i++ << "\n";
            if(mod_d.count((60 - f) % 60) > 0) ans += mod_d.at((60 - f) % 60) * (((60 - f) % 60) == f ? s - 1 : s);
        }

        return ans / 2;
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify your whole first loop to: `for(auto el : time) { mod_d[el % 60]++; }`. This'll work for the exact reason that your old code was failing :)

Comment: Yes, that is indeed correct and I had it like that at first. But, when it was acting odd, I thought this might be a problem xD. Thanks again for the suggestion :D :D