# Is making a std:map const then using at() function better than using the operator[]?

Tags: c++

Consider the two following snippets:

```cpp
bool foo(const int &lhs, const int &rhs)
{
    const std::map<int, int> bar{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};

    return bar.at(lhs) < bar.at(rhs);
}
```

and:

```cpp
bool foo(const int &lhs, const int &rhs)
{
    std::map<int, int> bar{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};

    return bar[lhs] < bar[rhs];
}
```

My questions:

- In the first snippet, is there a faster `const` function than `at()` that will not preform bound-checking?
- Which is better (faster, more idiomatic), for calling once and many times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I should use std::map::at to retrieve map element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236038/when-i-should-use-stdmapat-to-retrieve-map-element)

Comment: `Will the at() function stills perform bounds-checking even when bar is const?` Why would you ever assume otherwise? Anyway, yes. `What is better` What is used to measure "better"? How is "better" defined?

Comment: "Better" is a relative term. Now generally using `const` will allow the compiler to further optimize as you have guaranteed the values will not change. However, in this case there likely isn't much to be gained. So which is better? Neither really, it is more a matter of what you want the code to be.

Comment: If the map is constant, you assume that the expected key is present, therefore `at` is a better choice since it throws if the key is not present. `operator[]` inserts the key if the key is not present, therefore it cannot be used with a constant map. What’s better depends on your use case. Speed wise `at` might be faster since it does not insert the key if it is not found.